# How are the two versions of the Lumer-Phillips theorem given in the books of Engel/Nagel and Pazy related?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ be a densely-defined dissipative linear operator on $E$.

[In the book of Engel and Nagel](https://books.google.com/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%22For+a+densely+defined,+dissipative+operator%22&source=bl&ots=2RT76y5T-z&sig=ACfU3U02wnTcEBPZA5kTkmFqvtO90PMfBA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih_sngkobhAhWKjqQKHexmBcwQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22For%20a%20densely%20defined%2C%20dissipative%20operator%22&f=false), I've found the following verison of the Lumer-Phillips theorem:

> **Version 1**: The closure $(\mathcal D(\overline A),\overline A)$ of $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is the generator of a contraction semigroup if and only if $\lambda\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal D(A)}-A$ has dense range for some (and hence all) $\lambda>0$.

Now, [in the book of Pazy](https://books.google.com/books?id=DQvpBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22pazy%22+%22is+dissipative+and+there+is+a%22&source=bl&ots=jOWShdHxO2&sig=ACfU3U3ckwHGMmvwO7Ld3-8L-7ycu4KGzw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6rcjOk4bhAhXS16QKHZz6AeoQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22pazy%22%20%22is%20dissipative%20and%20there%20is%20a%22&f=false), I've found a different version:

> **Version 2**: The range of $\lambda\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal D(A)}-A$ is $E$ for some $\lambda>0$ if and only if $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is the generator of a strongly continuous contraction semigroup.

**Question 1**: How are these two versions related? For example, if $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is the generator of a contraction semigroup, version 1 only yields that $\lambda\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal D(A)}-A$ has dense range for all $\lambda>0$. How do we see that these ranges are actually the whole space $E$? Clearly, the crucial thing must be that not only the closure $(\mathcal D(\overline A),\overline A)$ but $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ itself is the generator of a contraction semigroup.

**Question 2**: In version 1, there is no strong continuity claim on the semigroup. Is this a mistake in the book or are we not able to conclude the strong continuity of the contraction semigroup generated by $(\mathcal D(\overline A),\overline A)$ if $\lambda\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal D(A)}-A$ has dense range for some $\lambda>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $A$ is a closed dissipative operator, then the range of $\lambda-A$ is closed for all $\lambda>0$. In fact, if $(\lambda x_n-A x_n)$ is Cauchy, then
   $$
   \|x_n-x_m\|\leq \frac 1 \lambda\|(\lambda-A)(x_n-x_m)\|.
   $$
   Hence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and thus $(Ax_n)$ is Cauchy as well. Since $A$ is closed, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\in D(A)$ and
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}(\lambda-A)x_n=(\lambda-A)\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\in \mathrm{ran}(\lambda-A).
   $$
2. If a contraction semigroup has a densely defined generator, then it is strongly continuous. This result is also somewhere in the book of Engel an Nagel, but the argument is quite simple: Trajectories starting in the domain of the generator are clearly continuous, and the uniform bound $\|T_t\|\leq 1$ allows one to extend this continuity to all trajectories starting in the closure of the domain of the generator.